# Is it possible to convert the router to work directly as a gateway?

Tags: networking, router, gateway

Is it possible to convert the router (for example a ASUS RT-AC66U) to work directly as a VDSL gateway, excluding then the gateway provided by the ISP?

And I mean physically, that is, no bridge mode, the router directly receiving the cable provided by the ISP. My ISP provides me IPoE with DHCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless the router you have has a VDSL modem baked in. The RT-AC66U does not (it's a great router - I use one).

It is certainly possible to purchase such a device ([example](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/dsl-modems-routers/D7000.aspx), but there are many others from other brands).

Answer (score 1):

This router does not support that type of connection; it's missing the port required. You mention no bridge mode, making me think you are against custom firmware. That being said, the first thing on any device is to make sure it's clean.

https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-3447/product_id-25596/year-2018/Asus-Rt-ac66u-Firmware.html

Those are two bad vulnerabilities, and to support what you are asking, I would flash the device with custom firmware that is maintained and updated regularly. If not your internal network will likely be compromised.

After flashing, you can put a modem device on the WAN port to handle the connection from VDSL to WAN RJ45. I highly recommend intrusion detection software. Hope this helps.